# Is ‘most’ for all the adjectives in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

Is the ‘most’ here for all the adjectives after it. Is there any general rule to be applied in such cases?

> Evolution, ecology, and population biology have given us tremendous
> understanding and insights, but have for the most part missed one of
> the **most** *important*, *interesting*, *exciting*, *explanatory*, and *unifying*
> aspects of evolution, ecology, and how ecosystems function. This is
> that organisms, species, and life itself generate the vast majority of
> the biodiversity on Earth, much more than would be present from
> physical and chemi- cal factors alone.

Comment: Given that punctuation marks the adjectives as being in coordination, i.e. they each separately modify "aspects ...", then "most" appears to modify just the first adjective, "important". But I doubt if that's what the writer intended.

Comment: The rule is that you need to use context in deciding whether an adverb modifies just one or all of the adjectives.

Comment: I agree with Peter Shor, but "one of the most" is fairly vague anyway, so it doesn't really matter. There's not a precise definition for "one of the most interesting" vs just "interesting".

Comment: And what does the context in the OP's sentence tell you?

Comment: ' ... have for the most part missed one of the most important, one of the most interesting, one of the most exciting, one of the most explanatory, and one of the most unifying aspects ... ' is the only grammatical way to expand this (there being a listing comma after 'important'). (The expansion is grammatical, but stylishly unwise as clunky)

Comment: "... one of the [most important], [interesting], [exciting], [explanatory], and [unifying] aspects of evolution, ecology, and how ecosystems function" is possible but unlikely.

Comment: @BillJ: I disagree. The only sane way to interpret this is that _most_ applies to all the adjectives.

Comment: It depends on context. Would anybody think *the very blue, warm water of the lake* means *the very blue and very warm water of the lake*.